# finding duplicate values oracle SQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server, oracle

I am trying to make a oracle SQL statement to tell me how many surveys have been done on each property.

I have one table - `property`: 
[image: property table]

and another here - `survey`:

[image: survey table]

I used the below statement to complete this but as seen in the resulting table it still shows the duplicates as separate entries so the count function only ever counts 1.

[image: resulting table]

```
SELECT property.property_id, property.property_address_first_line, survey.survey_id, survey.date_of_viewing, count( property.property_id) as "number_of_surveys"        
    from property
    inner join survey
    on (survey.property_id = property.property_id)
    group by property.property_id, property.property_address_first_line, survey.survey_id, survey.date_of_viewing
    order by property.property_id;
```

Many thanks

Comment: Don't post images for sample data, It may be hard to recreate the scenario when required. Always post in the plain-text form.

Comment: Is this Oracle DB or Oracle MySQL? The question is tagged both ways.

Comment: Tag properly!!!!  MySQL <> Oracle <> SQL Server!!!  Which one is this???

Comment: Do you need the survey_id and date_of_viewing? The problem is "group by" will only count the results that are completely equals, and since every survey has an unique id, this is not going to work. I recommend you to remove this columns from your query and verify if the result is what you expect.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your feedback, I apologise for any confusion with the tags I am new to stackoverflow and should have structured the tags better and read the requirements. Edumelzer, you are correct, I have done that now

Comment: @Eric (and others) - while in 99.9% of cases we do, indeed, need to know the specific database product, I believe in this case it will make no difference. I don't know MySQL or SQL Server, but I assume the syntax for this most basic SELECT statement is the same (and the same as that required by the SQL Standard) in all dialects.

Comment: @JackChurchill - why **inner** join? In most cases, your report should show all the properties, even those with zero surveys (which therefore are not present in the `surveys` table). You do that with an **outer** join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the `survey.survey_id, survey.date_of_viewing` fields from your query if you want to know how many surveys a particular property id took

```
SELECT property.property_id, property.property_address_first_line, count( survey.survey_id) as "number_of_surveys"        
    from property
    left outer join survey
    on (survey.property_id = property.property_id)
    group by property.property_id, property.property_address_first_line
    order by property.property_id;
```

Comment: Imagine there are 100 properties and 10 surveys per property on average, so 1,000 surveys total. If we join first, and then group by and count, the join will be 100 x 1000 rows. If instead we group by and count first (in the surveys table by itself, using property_id for grouping), and only then join to the property table, the join will be 100 x 100 rows. The group by and count is for 1000 rows either way. So it is more efficient to count first (in a subquery), and only then join the two tables. Perhaps the Optimizer will do that, but it is best to write it that way from the start.

Comment: I also edited to change from `inner join` to `left outer join` - there may be properties on which no surveys were done (yet). In most cases, they should still be shown, with a count of 0.

Comment: @mathguy  its not for certain that joining to a derived table will be more efficient.. most likely it would be the same performance, just relocating a compute scaler..  Plus, if you want to show 0 for properties without surveys, you'd have to coalesce the result of your subquery because the counts would be null if the property did not exist